# What form of "подъехать" is "подвести"?

Tags: глаголы

I have looked at the conjugation page for this verb ( ["Cooljugator"](http://cooljugator.com/ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)), but this form of the verb seems to not be present on the page.

Comment: @ShadowMecc - the question is incorrect since "подъехать", "подвезти" ("з", not "c") are different verbs, and that's the way it is.

Comment: @shabunc, if he (she) had known it he (she) wouldn't have asked.

Comment: Both "-ть" and "-ти" endings denote an infinitive. So it's totally unclear what is the question about.

Comment: @V.V true, but so far this question is not helpful for a wider audience (in my opinion) neither will be the answer, that's why I left a comment. It is sort of answer - and the answer is that question is incorrect.

Comment: In general, these are two distinct verbs that are not forms of one another. Besides that, the imperative (“Simple Command”) Cooljugator gives for this verb “подъехать” are just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no form of `"подъехать"`, that sounds `"подвести"`. Both are infinitives of different words.

- Подъехать means "drive up (to)"
- Подве**с**ти has to do with walking, leading, guiding or directing and means "bring somebody or something closer (to)", "insert something under something" (drive one end beneath the other)
- Подве**з**ти has to do with driving a vehicle and means "to deliver", "to give a lift"

"подве**з**ти" is a little bit closer to "подъехать" as both have to do with vehicle driving, but they are different too.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Paul's answer, "подвести" can also mean "to let [someone] down".

It's a figurative term, I think it comes from "to walk [someone] under [something]", I don't remember what the origin of this particular use is, unfortunately.

Comment: "To walk someone under the monastery", an adorable place of exile? Still used as an idiom.

Comment: ha, that could be it!